.NET MAUI Application: The app crashed when we installed it from TestFlight
I am working on a .NET MAUI application. The app runs successfully on both a physical device and a simulator when deployed directly from Visual Studio Code on a Mac. However, when the app is deployed to TestFlight and installed on a physical device, it crashes.
Below are the steps I followed to deploy the app to TestFlight from Visual Studio for Mac:

Switched from Debug mode to Release mode.
Verified the project settings using the .NET Archive: Settings command.
Cleaned the project using the .NET: Clean command.
Rebuild the project using the .NET: Rebuild command.
After a successful rebuild, published the app using the .NET Archive: Publish iOS command.
During this step, I selected the signing identity and distribution profile.



After publishing, the .IPA file was generated at:
project/bin/release/.net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/publish/AppName.ipa.



Uploaded the .IPA file to the Transporter app.
Delivered the file to TestFlight using the Transporter app.
Managed the build on TestFlight.

The visual Studio Code for Mac Version: 1.95.3
Xcode Version: 16.2
Transporter Version: 1.3.2
Can you suggest a solution for the crashing issue?
New Findings:
If I run the project in Debug Mode, getting the below warnings and problems on Visual Studio Code:
Warnings:
/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'SQLiteNetExtensions 2.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-ios18.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
ld : warning : -bitcode_process_mode is no longer supported and will be ignored [/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/Users/.nuget/packages/xamarin.firebase.ios.core/8.10.0.3/lib/net6.0-ios15.4/Firebase.Core.resources/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework/ios-arm64/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework/GoogleUtilitiesComponents : warning MT7091: The framework /Users/.nuget/packages/xamarin.firebase.ios.core/8.10.0.3/lib/net6.0-ios15.4/Firebase.Core.resources/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework/ios-arm64/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app. [/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/FAnlytcs-8.9.1/FirebaseAnalytics-8.9.1/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics : warning MT7091: The framework /Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/FAnlytcs-8.9.1/FirebaseAnalytics-8.9.1/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/FirebaseAnalytics.framework is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app. [/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement : warning MT7091: The framework /Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app. [/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]

Problems:
[{
    "resource": "/Users/.nuget/packages/xamarin.firebase.ios.core/8.10.0.3/lib/net6.0-ios15.4/Firebase.Core.resources/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework/ios-arm64/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework/GoogleUtilitiesComponents",
    "owner": "maui",
    "code": "MT7091",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "The framework /Users/.nuget/packages/xamarin.firebase.ios.core/8.10.0.3/lib/net6.0-ios15.4/Firebase.Core.resources/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework/ios-arm64/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app. [/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]",
    "source": "maui",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
[{
    "resource": "/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj",
    "owner": "maui",
    "code": "NU1701",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Package 'SQLiteNetExtensions 2.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-ios18.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.",
    "source": "maui",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
[{
    "resource": "/Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/FAnlytcs-8.9.1/FirebaseAnalytics-8.9.1/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics",
    "owner": "maui",
    "code": "MT7091",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "The framework /Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/FAnlytcs-8.9.1/FirebaseAnalytics-8.9.1/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/FirebaseAnalytics.framework is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app. [/Users/Downloads/projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]",
    "source": "maui",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
[{
    "resource": "/Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement",
    "owner": "maui",
    "code": "MT7091",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "The framework /Users/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app. [/Users/Downloads/Projectfolder/ProjectName/Appname/Appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]",
    "source": "maui",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]


You can’t solve it until you identify the cause.  What do the logs show?  Have you tried installing any crash reporting tools?

@Jason, I have checked the crash report from Xcode. But I didn't get any reason for crashing the app. Could you please suggest any solution to find the cause?

I already did.  Use a crash reporting tool like sentry or raygun

@Jason, I have updated the question with new findings. Could you please check it?

No, the information you posted seems unrelated and you are ignoring the main piece of advice I gave you.  Good luck.
